# D3 Sorting Bar Chart Error n.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, svg

I have the problem that everytime i try to execute my function sortBars(), I get the console error "Uncaught TypeError: n.each is not a function" in the console. I haven't found anything in relation to my problem.

Heres my JS Code:

```
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(d3.name);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);


var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>"+ d.name +"</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.value + "</span>";
  })


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("shit.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.name = d.name;
        d.value = d.value;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
  .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
});

var sortOrder = false;
var sortBars = function () {
    sortOrder = !sortOrder;

    sortItems = function (a, b) {
        if (sortOrder) {
            return a.value - b.value;
        }
        return b.value - a.value;
    };

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .sort(sortItems)
        .transition()
        .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return xAxis(i);
    });


};

d3.select("#sort").on("click", sortBars);

function randomSort() {

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .sort(sortItems)
        .transition()
        .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return xAxis(i);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from `xAxis(i)`. You probably wanted to use `x` instead, right?
However, you will also need to sort the `x` scale if you want the sorting to work properly:

```
var data = svg.selectAll(".bar").data();
x.domain(data.sort(sortItems).map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/50y288ew/